# random data in a data frame:difficulty in creating

Tags: r

I thought that I at least understood how to form a data frame, but I cannot solve my problem.
I want to create a data frame with columns names of ID, Col1 to 5 and populate each row with, in this instance, an ID number 759 to 755 and five randomly chosen numbers between 1 and 9. So something like:

```
ID  N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  
759  2  7   1   5   3  
758  3  7   9   8   2  
.   .   .
```

I have tried various ways, but either get a change in the column names or an error in the number of columns compared with the vector.
My latest "effort"

```
df<- data.frame(row.names =NULL)
df[1,] <-c(759, sample(1:9, 5)
colnames(df) = c("ID","N1", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5")
```

Eventually I want to iterate through the data and work out which data point occurred when and how long ago. ID could be replaced with a date. I am totally new to R  and totally illogical in thought(!),so all help is gratefully received. I cannot find an answer on the site to clear up my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
cbind(ID = 759:755, as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 5*5, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5)))
   ID V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 759  5  5  6  3  9
2 758  3  4  1  4  7
3 757  2  3  7  2  5
4 756  1  2  3  6  2
5 755  9  9  8  7  8
```

Comment: Thank you for such quick hel, both of you. I need to do a lot of reading!!

Comment: @user1478335, If you want each row to contain 5 _unique_ numbers of the sequence 1:9 (i.e. sample without replacement), J.R.'s answer will be right for your. If you want to sample with replacement, my answer will be fine (and probably faster since it avoids the loops that `replicate` does). As you see, for example, in row 1, number 5 occurs twice.

Answer (score 2):

You could always do something like:

```
df <- cbind( 759:755, t(replicate(5, sample(1:9, 5))))
df <- as.data.frame( df )
colnames(df) = c("ID", paste0("N",1:5) )
   ID N1 N2 N3 N4 N5
1 759  6  8  5  3  2
2 758  4  2  3  1  6
3 757  5  7  4  8  3
4 756  5  2  4  6  3
5 755  6  2  8  4  1
```

you should probably take a look at the difference between `sample(1:9, 5)` and `sample(1:9, 5, replace = TRUE)`

Comment: Is there a way to get unique values? Have tried replace=FALSE but raises an error "Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'"

Comment: I mean no duplicates in a row

Comment: @user1478335 my answer gives you just that. A sample of size 5 from 1:9 without replacement allocated to each row (ID), eg. no duplicates in each row. That's the reason I use `replicate()`.

Comment: O.K But I manage to get duplicates in rows using this... I have copied it exactly ( I think) , but will check again

Comment: Recopied and now seems Fine. I wonder what I did to create this error??

Comment: Perfect. Hmm, hard to say, but this doesn't give you dupes.

Comment: @user1478335, please accept J.R.'s answer instead of mine if this one does what you wanted.